# mountable engine's scaffold generated functional test fails on named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Environment:

- ruby 1.9.3p194
- rails 3.2.8

When I create rails' mountable engine 'MyEngine' and generate scaffold on 'post' model, functional test fails even I modified by the following steps:

1. create mountable engine by:

   > ```
   > $ rails plugin new my_engine --mountable
   > $ cd my_engine
   > $ rake db:create; rake db:migrate; rake db:setup
   > $ rails g scaffold post name zip
   > $ rake db:migrate
   > ```
2. 'rake test' fails as follows:

   > ```
   > $ rake test
   > NoMethodError: undefined method `posts' for
   > <MyEngine::PostsControllerTest:0xacd1fa4> 
   > ...my_engine/test/functional/my_engine/posts_controller_test.rb:6:in
   > 'block in <class:PostsControllerTest>'
   > ...
   > ```
3. According to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4971 and
   http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html "5.1 Functional tests",
   I modified two things:

   1. append the following flagment to test/test_helper.rb:

      > ```
      > class ActiveSupport::TestCase
      >   fixtures :all
      > end
      > ```

      recreate test DB manually as follows since "Could not find table 'my_engine_posts'"
      error happened:

      > $ (export RAILS_ENV=test; rake db:drop; rake db:create; 
      >      rake db:migrate; rake db:setup)
   2. modify test/functional/my_engine/posts_controller_test.rb as:

      > ```
      >  module MyEngine
      >    class PostsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
      >      setup do
      >        @post = my_engine_posts(:one)
      >      end       ^^^^^^^^^^
      >      ...
      >      test "should get index" do
      >        get :index, use_route: :my_engine
      >                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      > ```

However, still rake test fails at the following step:

> test_should_create_post(MyEngine::PostsControllerTest):
>      NoMethodError: undefined method `post_path' for...

where 'post_path' named route is used in the scaffold-generated functional test.
I think named routes looks OK because:

> ```
> $ rake app:routes
> my_engine  /my_engine MyEngine::Engine
>
> Routes for MyEngine::Engine:
>     posts GET    /posts(.:format)          my_engine/posts#index
>           POST   /posts(.:format)          my_engine/posts#create  new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)      my_engine/posts#new
> edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format) my_engine/posts#edit
>      post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      my_engine/posts#show
>           PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)      my_engine/posts#update
>           DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      my_engine/posts#destroy
> ```

Interesting thing is that similar step for rails app (not plugin) scaffold generated functional test works (of course!) as follows:

> ```
>  $ rails new my_app
>  $ cd my_app/
>  $ rake db:create; rake db:migrate; rake db:setup
>  $ rails g scaffold post name zip
>  $ rake  db:migrate
>  $ rake test
> ```

I very appreciate if anybody help me how to pass scaffold generated functional test on mountable engine!

Answer (score 3):

Solved by adding this to `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
class ActionController::TestCase
  include MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Change `MyEngine` to your own engine name.

---

Original idea comes from RSpec solution outlined in http://www.matthewratzloff.com/blog/2011/09/21/testing-routes-with-rails-3-1-engines/#comment-1572

Answer (score 1):

My conclusion at this time is not to use named route in functional test.  For example:

```
assert_redirected_to posts_path
  ↓
assert_redirected_to controller: 'my_engine/posts'
```

I understand that there is routing proxy like main_app and/or my_engine as http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html "6.3 Routes" mentions.  It works on controller and view, but it doesn't work on functional test (although named route is supported at functional test of *usual app*, not of mountable engine).  Named route with routing proxy may be able to use at test, but I couldn't find out the way at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these to the generated test_helper.rb:

```
def post_path(post)
  "/my_engine/posts/#{post.to_param}"
end

def posts_path
  '/my_engine/posts'
end
```

It worked for me.

Comment: With a little metaprogramming these two methods could also be generalized... :)